# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Tags: discord.js

I am getting this error error when trying to add a role a member when they have an invite link in their status
Error:

```js
C:\Users\Woody\Documents\Giveaway\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:93
        throw new TypeError('INVALID_TYPE', 'roles', 'Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes');
              ^

TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.
    at GuildMemberRoleManager.add (C:\Users\Woody\Documents\Giveaway\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:93:15)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Woody\Documents\Giveaway\index.js:61:39)
    at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at PresenceUpdateAction.handle (C:\Users\Woody\Documents\Giveaway\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\PresenceUpdate.js:39:19)
    at Object.module.exports [as PRESENCE_UPDATE] (C:\Users\Woody\Documents\Giveaway\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\PRESENCE_UPDATE.js:4:33)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Woody\Documents\Giveaway\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Woody\Documents\Giveaway\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Woody\Documents\Giveaway\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Woody\Documents\Giveaway\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INVALID_TYPE'
}
```

And this is my code:

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get("984959434256179221");
    const member = newPresence.member
    const activities = member.presence.activities[0];
  
    if (activities && (activities.state.includes( ".gg/s7trZ2NF" ) || activities.state.includes("discord.gg/s7trZ2NF" ))) {
      return newPresence.member.roles.add(role)
    } else {
      if(member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
        newPresence.member.roles.remove(role)
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is ``newPresence.activites``` defined?  If so, where is it defined?

Comment: ive fixed it am just getting a error for 

        throw new TypeError('INVALID_TYPE', 'roles', 'Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes');


TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.

Comment: What is this `role` of yours? Can you add the `role code` on your post aswell?

Comment: Please include the error in your post.

Comment: Done! ive did both

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `let role = roles.cache.get("roleId")` just simply do `member.roles.add(roleId);` or make it `let role = "roleId"` instead

Currently you're trying to get a role from the cache, so chances are the role is uncached and returning nothing, hence the error.

Secondly in your if check, you only need the first `includes()`. Includes will check for *any* matches and not specific matches.

i.e. `discord.gg/code` and `.gg/code` will both return true in that condition

The error in the title seems to be completely unrelated to the error you've provided as well as the code, this answer only matches the actual descritpion of the problem.